# How to display a user's get_full_name() instead of the username in a Django model form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model that references a `ForeignKey(User)` field.

When a user selects an item on his form I would like them to be able to see the `get_full_name()` instead of just the `username`.

```
class Books(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: Always name your model class in singular, write `Book` instead of `Books`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django forms: how to dynamically create ModelChoiceField labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958792/django-forms-how-to-dynamically-create-modelchoicefield-labels)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This can be done several ways.

Create a proxy subclass of `User` and override its `__unicode__()` method to return user's full name.

```
class UserFullName(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()
```

Now in your model form, use `UserFullName` to retrieve users.

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    author = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=UserFullName.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

---

Another way is to dynamically populate choices in form's constructor.

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BookForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        users = User.objects.all()
        self.fields['author'].choices = [(user.pk, user.get_full_name()) for user in users]

    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

---

Perhaps, the most "djangonic" way is demonstrated by lazerscience as an answer to the similar question *[Django forms: how to dynamically create ModelChoiceField labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958792/django-forms-how-to-dynamically-create-modelchoicefield-labels)*. It subclasses `ModelChoiceField` and overrides its `label_from_instance()` method that is intended to provide choice labels.

```
class UserFullnameChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return smart_unicode(obj.get_full_name())

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    author = UserFullnameChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

Comment: Thanks, the last option (most "djangonic" way) seems the cleanest and worked fine. Don't forget a `from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Török Gábor's answer, the following can be used for `ModelMultipleChoiceField`s:

```
class UserFullnameMultipleChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return smart_unicode(obj.get_full_name())

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    authors = UserFullnameMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(),
                                              help_text=Book.authors.field.help_text)
```

Note that I have copy `help_text` so the default help text ('Use control or command to select multiple...').