# django how to display users full name in FilteredSelectMultiple

Tags: python, django

i am trying to use FilteredSelectMultiple widget to display list of users. currently it is displaying only username. I have tried to override the label_from_instance as seen below but it does not seem to work. how can it get to display users full name.

```
class UserMultipleChoiceField(FilteredSelectMultiple):
    """
    Custom multiple select Feild with full name
    """                                                                                                                                                                 
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
              return "%s" % (obj.get_full_name())

class TicketForm(forms.Form):
    cc_to  = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('username'), widget=UserMultipleChoiceField("CC TO", is_stacked=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little late, but I think it might help people trying to solve a similar problem: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1642/

Answer (score 15):

The simplest solution is to put the following in a **models.py** where `django.contrib.auth.models.User` is imported:

```
def user_unicode_patch(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

User.__unicode__ = user_unicode_patch
```

This will overwrite the `User` model's `__unicode__()` method with a custom function that displays whatever you want.

Comment: I like this approach but would prefer `return self.get_full_name()` to avoid re-defining how a name is rendered.

Comment: Just a tiny improvement of mine: `User.__str__ = lambda user: user.get_full_name() or user.get_username()`

Answer (score 4):

(For future reference)

**You should subclass ModelMultipleChoiceField instead:**

```
class UserMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    """
    Custom multiple select Feild with full name
    """
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
          return obj.get_full_name()


class TicketForm(forms.Form):
    cc_to  = UserMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=User.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('username'),
            widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("CC TO", is_stacked=True)
        )
```

**Another solution is to subclass User and use it in your query set**
(*as in this question:* [Django show get_full_name() instead or username in model form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966483/django-show-get-full-name-instead-or-username-in-model-form))

```
class UserFullName(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        ordering = ["username"]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()

class TicketForm(forms.Form):
    cc_to  = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=UserFullName.objects.filter(is_active=True),
            widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("CC TO", is_stacked=True)
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to override User model **unicode** method. You can create new model, like this:

```
class ExtendedUser(User): # inherits from django.contrib.auth.models.User
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the same as jnns and also override the _meta ordering list, to order users list by their user full name.

```
# hack for displaying user's full name instead of username and order them by full name
def user_unicode_patch(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
User.__unicode__ = user_unicode_patch
User._meta.ordering = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

I've added this at the UserProfile model file.
I don't thing this is the best way of doing that, but for sure is very easy and practical. Tested in Django 1.4

For Django 1.5 after, it will be easier to do that, since we'll have more control of the User model.

Answer (score 0):

**let's say your models are**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model) :
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def full_name(self):
        """

        : Return the first_name plus the last_name, with space in between.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.second_name)
        return full_name.strip()
```

Comment: Did you leave out a part of your answer? The text seems entirely out of place without an explanation

Comment: @Zoe just describing how to get a full name when you don't want to use  Django define names such as first  name and last name on the model