# Issue with ForeignKey in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a form which is linked with a ForeignKey.

```
Model.py

    enter code here
    model.py

class CreateD(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    db = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    iss  = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True ,default='A')
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'add_d'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.db,self.iss)


class Assignment(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    assign_to = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    db_name = models.ForeignKey(CreateDb,related_name='set__dbname')
    issue_type = models.ForeignKey(CreateDb,related_name='set_issuetype')
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'assignment'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.db_name,self.issue_type)

form.py

class AssignmentForm(ModelForm):


class Meta:
    model = Assignment
    exclude = ('id','date','assign_to')


assign.html 

   {{forms.as_p}}


Data in the sql :
   id  db iss
   1   A   AB
   2   B   BA




Output genrated from html page is 

   db_name    : A AB (choice field)
                B BA
   issue_type : A AB (choice field)
                B BA


Actually i Need a output like below in html:

    db_name    : A (choice field)
                 B 
   issue_type : AB (choice field)
                BA
```

Please help me on this ...........

Comment: Not sure I understand, but is it to do with the __unicode__ you have defined?  If you change the def for CreateD to return self.db instead, does it work?

Comment: It would help if you explain what's not working.

Comment: I want to fetch only db under db_name and iss under issue_type.but my problem is in the choice field i am getting db and iss for both choice field .because Unicode  returns db and iss.if i remove iss it only db .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right you want to change the labels in the select box, by default they are generated via the model's `__unicode__` method, but you can override the form field's `label_from_instance` method and choose another way to do this; see [Django forms: how to dynamically create ModelChoiceField labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958792/django-forms-how-to-dynamically-create-modelchoicefield-labels)!