# Django Query Sets

Tags: python, django

I have the following in one of my forms:

```
self.fields['advisor'].queryset = User.objects.filter(groups__name='advisor')
```

The only problem is that it displays the `username` in the drop down box. What I would like to do is display the `first_name` then `last_name` to make it more human readable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ModelChoiceField` has a `label_from_instance` method which can be changed in a subclass to use something other than the model `__unicode__` method.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label

Comment: I understanding what the docs are say, but then how would I use it in `forms.py`?

Comment: Thanks... I get it now. I can implement it in `forms.py` with `advisor = UserModelChoiceField(queryset = User.objects.filter(groups__name='advisor'))`. Thanks to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2959870/563247

Answer (score 0):

According to this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/), try this quick and dirty code :

```
u = User.objects.filter(groups__name='advisor')
self.fields['advisor'].queryset = u.get_first_name_display() + " " + u.get_last_name_display()
```

Comment: hummm... it doesn't like `get_first_name_display()`

Comment: It's the default user that ships with django

Comment: You could look at using the [get_full_name method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/23b941845887e3b967d76cb115d3bc51e7310b71/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L284), but it can only be called on a single User object, not on a queryset.